# How do I start the rails server as part of my integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails / open source development and I'm using Test Unit to write integration tests in conjunction with Capybara / WebDriver

How do I ensure that the Rails server is both running AND ready, prior to executing my integration tests?

I tried the following in my test_helper.rb:

```
server_running = false
path = File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", "pids", "server.pid")
if  FileTest.exist? path
  begin
    pid = File.read(path).to_i
    server_running = true if Process.getpgid pid
  rescue Errno::ESRCHfound
  end
end

if !(server_running)
  puts "Starting Rails Server"
  system "rails s"
else
  puts "Rails Server already started"
end
```

Problem is the tests never run because technically "system 'rails s'" never completes

So I next tried detached mode via "rails s -d" but this doesn't work for me (raised as separate question elsewhere on SO) and the server.pid is not present in the tmp folder either

So last I tried system "rails s &". Problem with this is, my unit tests start executing immediately before the Rails Server is actually ready. I guess what I really need is a way to start the Rails Server and figure out (either by polling or some callback) when it's actually ready to start accepting requests

Appreciate any advice and guidance on best practices regarding this. I've been recommended using Spork further down the road for CI but for now, I'd like to just stick to the tools I have (TestUnit, Capybara, WebDriver) unless absolutely necessary

EDIT: in my test_helper.rb I have the following at the end of the file

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::DSL

  def setup
    Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
    Capybara.run_server = true 
    Capybara.server_port = 3001
    Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3001"
  end


  def teardown
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end
end
```

One of my tests merely has visit('/linkedin/importprofile') - doing so yields the following exception:

```
  1) Error:
test_should_display_previously_imported_LinkedIn_data_in_Basic_Profile_fields(LinkedinTest):
Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError: Unable to load URL: http://localhost:3001/linkedin/importprofile because of error loading http://localhost:3001/linkedin/importprofile: Unknown error
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:215:in `check'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:152:in `command'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:18:in `visit'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:29:in `visit'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:193:in `visit'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
    /home/blue18hutthutt/Sites/pd_frontend/test/integration/linkedin_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:LinkedinTest>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never need to manually start a Rails server to run tests. When needed, the driver will start one automatically and shut it down when the test run finishes. The default Rack::Test driver doesn't even need a server process since it interfaces with Rack directly.

If you're still having issues after removing your manual server-starting code, I would first make sure you've set up Capybara to work with Test::Unit [as described in this section of the README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-testunit). (**Edit:** Though it appears you have, manually specifying `server_port` and `app_host` is likely interfering with something, as discussed in the comments below.)

Comment: The problem is, I have an integration test that involves an OAuth scenario, which requires visiting a page externally to my Rails application as part of the work-flow, and the default Rack::Test driver doesn't permit this (I'm using the :webkit driver for this scenario)

Comment: The driver will automatically start a server instance when needed. There's nothing to be gained from trying to start up your own server instance; even if you did, the driver wouldn't use it. If your real problem is that you're having issues testing a workflow that relies on third-party websites, that would be a whole different question. (This question is actually a good example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: In that case, if we take a step back and examine the problem of testing a workflow involving a third-party website, what would my options be? It'd have to be either Selenium WebDriver or WebKit, right? In either / both those cases, wouldn't I need the server to be running since, I believe 'the driver' only automatically starts a Rails server instance if and only if the current driver is the default Rack::Test driver (eg via the Capybara.run_server = true)

Comment: All drivers automatically start a server instance. Rack::Test, Selenium, Webkit, Poltergeist, all of them. You never need to do this manually. (Rack::Test starts an in-process Rack server, the others start a full Rails server akin to running `rails s`) As you suggest, browser-based drivers like Selenium and Webkit are indeed capable of accessing external sites. Is there some specific error or test failure you're getting that makes you think the problem lies with the Rails server?

Comment: I edited the original question to add some additional information. I concluded that I had to run "rails s" manually because I couldn't seem to call visit('/mypath') after setting the settings in the code snippet above. I didn't realize each driver automatically starts a server instance (couldn't find any documentation on this - in-depth documentation about features, in general has been hard to come by) ..if that's the case, what am I doing wrong preventing this from working?

Comment: Your explicit setting of `server_port` and `app_host` are probably preventing capybara-webkit from connecting to the Rails instance it starts automatically. Also, `run_server` is true by default, and `reset_sessions!` should only be necessary for non-Rails apps according to the Capybara README. So I would remove everything except the `include` and the `default_driver`.

Comment: Alas, I took your suggested and commented out the lines that explicitly set the server_port and app_host ..only thing I have now is setting the default_driver to :webkit. I now get the following 
error: Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError: Unable to load URL: file:///linkedin/importprofile because of error loading file:///linkedin/importprofile: Unknown error

Comment: Does your test inherit from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`? Does the same problem arise when you use Selenium instead? This is getting beyond my ability to remotely troubleshoot your issue -- you might be better off starting over with a new question containing your current code and the stack trace you're getting from it. I think your original question about trying to start a server has been answered at this point.

Comment: Aye it does inherit from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest and I agree, this is getting beyond the scope of the question. Appreciate your help though, I'm going to start from scratch with a fresh Rails application and try to write a bare-bones test and if that still has issues, will raise another question dedicated to that

Comment: That seems a reasonable approach. If you think this particular question has been adequately answered, could you accept it?